# Assigning a database value to a Python Variable

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

Making a simple script which grabs the latest value from the database and sends over HTTP GET to a destination

however when I use "mycursor.fetchone()" I get returned the value ""(Decimal('21.00'),)"

Am I missing something? I'd like to just extract a raw value

Code snippet:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT RAINFALL FROM WATHER_MEASUREMENT")
rainfall = mycursor.fetchone()

#create a URL variable 
 URL='https://*****'
 PARAMS = "temp={temperature}&pressure={pressure}&rh={humidity}&precip={rainfall}".format(**vars())

requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
```

Comment: What type of values are contained in the database? What result are you expecting? How does it differ from the one you got?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear. These are all integer values, i'd like to extract the integer and pass it through a variable into the HTTP request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetchone returns dict not value

add this after second line:

```
rainfall = rainfall['RAINFALL']
```

Comment: ok, as in. rainfall = mycursor.fetchone() 
followed by rainfall = rainfall['RAINFALL']

Comment: or use rainfall[0]